# i have been working on asp.net MVC ,unable to fire on change event in dropdownlistbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have created a controller by name AdmissionControlller there I have added two ActionResult functions: Create and Post Event

```
// POST: /Admission/Create
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
{
    try
    {
        // TODO: Add insert logic here
        return RedirectToAction("Index",collection);
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}

 //Return the List of Subject For the Class Selected 
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Details(string className)
{
    var subject = SubjectsModel.SelectSubjectsByClass(className);
    return PartialView("EntranceMarks", subject);
}
```

now in the view page

Create Page

```
<h2>
    Create</h2>
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
{%>
<%= Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Fields</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Id) %>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.PlNo) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PlNo) %>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PlNo) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdmissionNo) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AdmissionNo) %>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdmissionNo) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdmissionDate) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AdmissionDate) %>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdmissionDate) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName) %>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.MiddleName) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MiddleName) %>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MiddleName) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName) %>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.Class) %>
    </div>
    <%using (Ajax.BeginForm("Details", new AjaxOptions { 
                    UpdateTargetId = "EntranceMarks" }))
    { %>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%=Html.DropDownList("StudentClass")%>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.Section) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%=Html.DropDownList("Section")%>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label" id="EntranceMarks">
    </div>
    <%} %>      
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
<% } %>
<div>
    <%= Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
</div
```

Now when I change the dropdownlist box for class I  am unable to fire the event??

Comment: I know this is your first question, but it's rather difficult to understand. Please edit your post to fix the formatting of the code, remove all of the unnecessary code, then explain exactly what event you are talking about. It will really help others answer your question. Thanks.

Comment: Much better. I'm still not sure what you mean by "unable to fire the event". What do you want to happen?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the `onchange` handle when creating your dropdownlist. The `ChangeClass()` method referred to below is the name of a javascript function which you need to create.

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("StudentClass", new {onchange="ChangeClass()"})%>
```

You alternatively use Jquery and bind the `onchange` event to the dropdown list you are interested in.

```
$("#StudentClass").change(function() {
 // your logic goes here
 // if you need to populate some other part of the form
 // this method will probably have some ajax call to a specified
 // controller action which return your data.
});
```

Now if you mean that you want the form to be submitted when you change the drop down, this can be achieved with

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("StudentClass", new {onchange="this.form.submit()"})%>
```